# Variable value in gulp replace

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gulp, gulp-replace

I am currently working on creating a script that converts a html website into a WordPress template.

I know that you can replace text and other values in files with text.
But is there also a way to replace those with another variable's values?

> I want to change the template name to the name the user sets before this``

```
.pipe(replace('TEMPLATENAME', '<%= pkg.name %>'))
```

and ofcourse the output I get now is:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', '<%= pkg.name %>' ),) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is `TEMPLATENAME` to be replaced by the value in `pkg.name` you should do something like this:

```
.pipe(replace('TEMPLATENAME', pkg.name))
```

Comment: Thanks that is indeed what I needed.
I thought I had to use the <%= .. %> but without that it works thanks :)